# python 3: how to check if an object is a function?

Tags: python, class, function, python-3.x

Am I correct assuming that all functions (built-in or user-defined) belong to the same class, but that class doesn't seem to be bound to any variable by default?

How can I check that an object is a function?

I can do this I guess:

```
def is_function(x):
  def tmp()
    pass
  return type(x) is type(tmp)
```

It doesn't seem neat, and I'm not even 100% sure it's perfectly correct.

Comment: There are also objects with a __call__ method that can be called as a function.

Comment: All classes can be called as a function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in python2:

```
callable(fn)
```

in python3:

```
isinstance(fn, collections.Callable)
```

as Callable is an Abstract Base Class, this is equivalent to:

```
hasattr(fn, '__call__')
```

Comment: The `callable` function was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2 - so you can also use it w/ Python 3 if using a recent version of the interpreter. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=callable#callable for more information.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I check that an object is a function?

Isn't this same as checking for callables

```
hasattr(object, '__call__')
```

and also in python 2.x

```
callable(object) == True
```

Comment: it also applies to classes, but +1 anyway has it seems more in the logic of duck typing

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
def is_function(x):
    import types
    return isinstance(x, types.FunctionType) \
        or isinstance(x, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
```

Comment: but does this also check if it is of the same class ?

Comment: @Version, what do you mean by `if it is of the same class`?

Comment: `is` on type objects, yikes. If you must use explicit typechecks, at least use `isinstance()`, and preferably ask the `inspect` module to do it instead.

Comment: Explicit "type(object) is SomeType" is error-prone and has been long-ago replaced with `isinstance` - learn the new and improved coding idioms!

Comment: @Thomas, @Paul, you're right, answer updated. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Why is `type(object) is SomeType` error-prone? (Not that I want to use it, but I'm curious).

Answer (score -4):

```
try:
    magicVariable()
except TypeError as e:
    print( 'was no function' )
```

Comment: -1, you shouldn't have to execute the function to test it.

Comment: My code is not meant as a *test*. When you have a variable, the only reason why you would check if it is a function is because you want to use it. So instead of investing time in checking that beforehand, you should just use it as a function and handle the exception.

Comment: i +1'ed it because in the general case, I think you're right but there are definitely cases where one wants to know if one is dealing with a function without having any intent of executing it. Metaclasses and class decorators come to mind.

Comment: @poke: no, that is one reason. What if you want store the function? If you use this method it will be much more difficult to debug.

Comment: This doesn't work if the function raises a TypeError.

Comment: @dan_waterworth, I missed that. Now I wish I could undo my +1

Comment: @dan_waterworth: Okay, fair enough, but it's still a viable possibilty for a lot situations..

Comment: @aaronasterling: join the queue, there's a lot of votes I wish I could undo after people's comments.

Comment: sure, there are some situations where this works fine, but I happen to think that using callable or isinstance is more readable.

Comment: There are other reasons why you'd want to see if it is a function without executing it, but that code fragment does apply to many use cases. One problem is if the function through a type error inside of itself, it would report that it is not a function.

Comment: Doesn't work if the function takes at least one argument, in which case, calling it on zero arguments will cause a separate `TypeError`

Comment: I like this as a EAFP/LBYL solution. Do OP need to check, or just recover from doing and failing?